# How can a Witch gain access to Wizard spells for crafting

Tags: pathfinder-1e

I am currently rolling a level 11 Witch in a campaign with some friends. At 11th level I took the feat Craft Wondrous Items. This is all good except that many of the items that could be of use for the party require arcane spells that are not listed in the witches list of spells. For example: Permanency.

If stats are needed for an answer, my character has 26 Int, and 10 Cha. I am caster level 11 with 14 in UMD, 22 Knowledge Arcana, 22 Spellcraft.

What is the best way for me to gain access to the spells I need to craft some of the wondrous items? Or is it possible for me to still create the item without having the spells in my spell book?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You don't need these spells.  [Adding 5 to the DC of an item for crafting purposes allows you to bypass any one prerequisite](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic-items#TOC-Magic-Item-Creation), and can be done multiple times.  This should prove no obstacle to you, given your reasonable  spellcraft mod.  Remember to make some [Amazing Tools of Manufacture](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic-items/wondrous-items/wondrous-items/r-z/tools-amazing-tools-of-manufacture) at your earliest convenience, and that you can [have other people craft for you](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic-items#TOC-Magic-Item-Descriptions) (with you merely providing the feat that allows them to craft).

If you want to learn these spells anyways, increase your UMD as much as possible and buy Sorcerer-based [Pages of Spell Knowledge](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic-items/wondrous-items/wondrous-items/m-p/page-of-spell-knowledge).  Then you can prepare any wizard spells on the sorcerer spell list (which you have crafted and also have present in the spellbook-like bound set of Pages of Spell Knowledge you carry) if you can make a DC 21 UMD check per spell.  You may, depending on GM, also need to roll to emulate an appropriately high charisma score (current average total 17) and/or an appropriately high class level (current average 12), but neither of these are required by the RAW.  This covers all spells except Blood Transcription (which you get anyways), [Mnemonic Enhancer](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/m/mnemonic-enhancer), and [Mage's Lucubration](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/m/mage-s-lucubration).  This is sad, because those spells are awesome.

Please note: you probably don't have a spellbook, you have a witch's familiar instead.

Comment: Does that only add into Craft? Or does that apply to Spellcraft as well?

Comment: A witches familiar stores the witches spells and it cannot store non-witch spells. :/ But you answered the question with the 5DC increase, thankyou

Comment: @DanceSC the bonus is not the point of the item (and it adds only to the Craft roll involved in the magic item, not the spellcraft roll).  The massive time reduction is the point of the item (1000 gp/day and 8 hours of work --> 2000 gp/day and 1 hour of work).

Answer (score 2):

If you don't want to add 5 to the DC of the craft check, as Wanderer suggested (if you're concerned about making the check, for some reason), you can also get an NPC or another party member who has the spell to cast it for you.

[Looking at the Pathfinder SRD here (emphasis mine)](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic-items#TOC-Magic-Item-Creation)

> These prerequisites must be met for the item to be created. Most of the time, they take the form of spells that must be known by the item's creator (**although access through another magic item or spellcaster is allowed**).